# 1D Photonic Crystal Photonic Bandgap Example Confusion

Tags: optics, photonics

I am reading through *Optoelectronics & Photonic Principles* by Safa O. Kasap and am not understanding section 1.17 on Photonic Crystals. Here is an excerpt:
[image]

The book mentions how some waves suffer Bragg reflection (C,D in 1.51b) when they constructively interfere via the reflection to cause a full reflection. This makes sense to me, but the book follows by saying that these diffracted waves form standing waves that can be in two possible configurations, S1 or S2. They say "One of them, S1, has
most of its energy inside the n2, high refractive index layers, and hence has a lower frequency v1. S2 has most of its energy in the n1 layers and has a higher frequency v2; these are shown in Figure 1.51 (b)." Looking at the picture, I do not understand how they have different frequencies w1 and w2, as in the picture they look to be the same frequency wave just out of phase such that the peak of S1 occurs in n2 and the peak of S2 occurs in n1. I am self learning through this textbook so I think I may be misunderstanding something basic about the specific definition of w in this picture, as clearly these waves do not have different frequencies?

Thank you and let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify the question further.